# Is there any way to have a web page record sound from an iPad?

Tags: ipad, audio, microphone

I don't think this is currently possible with straight HTML (although I've heard that HTML5 may support this in the future):

I'd like a web app that can record audio from the iPad (and also, ideally iPhone).
This will not be an iOS app. It's a web page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. The only hardware functions you can get access to via HTML/JS are the location service and the accelerometer.